# Interface with Java Content Assist in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

As part of my plugin project, I'm thinking about interfacing with the content assist list displayed by Eclipse on Java files (I'm trying to re-order the list according to some external data).

I've seen some tutorials about creating a new content assist, but nothing about changing an existing one. Is that even possible? If it is, where should I start for modifying Java's Content Assist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the order of the content assist items with the extionsion point `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalSorters` which lets you register your own implementation of `ICompletionProposalSorter`.

The example below is from the plugin `org.eclipse.jdt.ui` which provides two completion proposal sorters:

```
<extension
    point="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalSorters">
    <proposalSorter
        id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.RelevanceSorter"
        name="%RelevanceSorter.name"
        class="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.RelevanceSorter"/>
    <proposalSorter
        id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.AlphabeticSorter"
        name="%AlphabeticSorter.name"
        class="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.AlphabeticSorter"/>
</extension>
```

The implementations of [AlphabeticSorter](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ui/blob/master/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/ui/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/text/java/AlphabeticSorter.java) and [RelevanceSorter](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ui/blob/master/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/ui/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/text/java/RelevanceSorter.java) might help you getting started with writing your own sorter.

Answer (score 3):

> Is that even possible?

No it's not. A good starting point for writing your own java-content assist is the Mylyn source-code. Mylyn is contributing an own (task-focussed) java content assist. Take a look at the bundle org.eclipse.mylyn.java.ui

HTH